# Laravel Scheduler task dynamically

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-queue, laravel-scheduler

I have implemented Task Scheduler in laravel. my schedule

```
$schedule->command('sms:reminder')->dailyAt('11:00')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Here I have set to `11AM` daily. but I want to configure this time in database through the User Dashboard.

How do I do that?

I thought to do this like ,

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->everyMinute()->skip(function () {
    //taking current time
    //fetching stored time in database.
    // compare both time- if equals return true else false
});
```

But, this will keep on hitting my DB every minute. I don't want to do that.

I am using Laravel 5.8;

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach is a good idea. But instead of hitting the DB, you can simply cache your time forever and update the cache whenever a change in that value occurs.

Comment: Do you have Redis in your techstack ?

Comment: @D.Petrov so, better I store the time in cache instead of tables right?

Comment: Hi Ersoy, No...

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran This would better the performance time, yes.

Comment: Can you please look into this question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738305/cron-job-in-ubuntu-creating-multiple-instances